# NestedScrollView inside CoordinatorLayout don't have smooth scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have some trouble trying to do a Smooth scrolling using a NestedScrollView inside a CoordinatorLayout. Now when I scroll It stops and don't have a smooth scroll, like when I scroll on a RecyclerView.

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

<include
    layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/eventDetailActivity_bottomRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <RelativeLayout
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_speakerPictureImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/bg_profile" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_speakerInfoRl"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/orange">

                <TextView
                    android:height="21dp"
                    android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_speakerLocationTextView"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/violet"
                    tools:text="Londres, Reino Unido"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:height="21dp"
                    android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_speakerEmailTextView"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/violet"
                    tools:text="Londres, Reino Unido"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_speakerDescriptionTextView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/grayA"
                tools:text="Cuantos estilos de ilustración existen en el mundo? Nosotros conocemos 30, y te los queremos enseñar a todos en un workshop tan exagerado y tenaz..."
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/lines_spacing"
                fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/plus_x3"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_eventTitleTextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/grayA"
                    tools:text="Event Title"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_eventDateTextView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/grayA"
                    tools:text="Event Date"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_eventLocationTextView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/grayA"
                    tools:text="Event Location"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/lines_spacing"
                    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<include
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar_dropshadow"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_bottomRelativeLayout"
    android:background="@color/violet"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_favoriteRelativeLayout"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventDetailActivity_favoriteTextView"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:text="@string/eventDetailActivity_addToFavs"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="11dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried putting the NestedScrollView on a Fragment but that doesn't worked.

Comment: Where is your recyleview?

Comment: I don't have a RecyclerView. I only said the smooth mode like a RecyclerView scrolls.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your problem? I have exactly the same problem. It really drives me nuts because there is no documentation for this and I don't know how to implement the scrolling feature inside the CoordinatorLayout.